# How to pass a nullable variable as a composable?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a `TopAppBar` switching its content while navigating. The goal is to use a flag and change the `navigationIcon`. But I can't pass the `Composable/null` as a parameter here. The code:

```
val navIcon = if (viewModel.isBackAvailable) NavIcon { navController.navigateUp() } else null

TopAppBar(navigationIcon = navIcon)// Required:(() → Unit)? Found:Unit?

@Composable
private fun NavIcon(navigate: () -> Unit) {
    IconButton(onClick = navigate) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ArrowBack,
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.navigate_back),
            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        )
    }
}
```

I can't pass something like an empty value `navigationIcon = {}` because it takes its space in this case, I need to use `null`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your code, `navIcon` is a result of `NavIcon` function call, which is unit. You need to have function reference there, you can do that like this:

```kotlin
val navIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = if (viewModel.isBackAvailable) {
    { NavIcon { navController.navigateUp() } }
} else null
```

Comment: Nice. Thought, Kotlin is smart enough to understand the type properly

Comment: Is it working for you without specifying the type explicitly? It can understand it's a function, but it doesn't allow calling `@Composable` functions from inside if I don't specify the type...

Comment: No, need to specify the type here `navIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)?`